# Android: Netrunner judge program

Tags: android-netrunner

Does Android: Netrunner have anything similar to Magic the Gathering's [judge program](http://magic.wizards.com/en/events/resources/judges)?

Answer (score 4):

Fantasy Flight Games doesn't currently have a judge program, the closest thing they have are the [floor rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/82/0b/820bc81b-e424-437a-af1a-e28fed5896f3/adn-floor-rules.pdf).

However at the start of 2015 they announced their intent to setup something like a judge program sometime this year, with a trial starting in the US initially.
It's possible they're delaying the program to see what happens with the Magic Judge system after the currently running lawsuits are settled.

Comment: Did anything ever happen with this in terms of a judge program being instigated for Netrunner?